# PHP - file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, html

Can someone help me to handle this error? I don't know what method or way to get rid of this error. Im new to php and starting to learn it. Can someone give me ideas?

here is the error :
[image]

here is my php code.

```
<?php

include_once('connection.php');

 $newsid = $_GET['news_id'];

    if(isset($_POST['esubmit'])){
        /* create a prepared statement */
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM news WHERE news_id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            /* bind parameters */
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $newsid);

            /* execute query */
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            /* get the result set */
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

            /* fetch row from the result set */
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        }

    }


    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

        if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
          $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
          /* Below is the line 30 causing the error*/
          $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
          $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"img/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
          $newsimage="img/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];

          $title = $_POST['titles'];
          $date = $_POST['dates'];
          $content = $_POST['contents'];

          $sql ="UPDATE news SET news_title ='$title', news_date ='$date', news_content = '$content', news_image ='$newsimage' WHERE news_id = '$newsid'";
          mysqli_query($con, $sql);
          echo "oh it worked ";
        }
        else{
          $title = $_POST['titles'];
          $date = $_POST['dates'];
          $content = $_POST['contents'];
          $sql ="UPDATE news SET news_title ='$title', news_date ='$date', news_content = '$content' WHERE news_id = '$newsid'";
          mysqli_query($con, $sql);
          echo "oh it worked again ";
        }

    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['esubmit'])){
        ?>

        <form method="post" action ="edit2.php?news_id=<?php echo $row['news_id']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Title<input type ="text" name ="titles" value="<?php echo $row['news_title']; ?>"/><br>
            Date<input type ="text" name="dates" value="<?php echo $row['news_date']; ?>" /><br>
            Content<textarea name="contents"><?php echo $row['news_content']; ?></textarea>
            <input class="form-control" id="image" name="image" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange='AlertFilesize();'/>
            <img id="blah" src="<?php echo $row['news_image']; ?>" alt="your image" style="width:200px; height:140px;"/>

            <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
        </form>

        <?php
    }

?>

<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#image").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` returns a temporary file, echo it out to see the kind of data it returns and it'll be clear what the error means. Also, why are you attempting to get the contents when you're not using `$image` again?

Comment: You're using `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` in your first query... why oh why aren't you using it for your other queries??? Your other queries are just adding the POST vars directly to the query string, making you wide open to SQL injection attack.

Comment: You should also check the `length` of `$_FILES['image']` array in the condition `if(isset($_FILES['image'])){`

Comment: why are you adding slashes?

Comment: @Martin i already edit it my questions sir. Please check again thanks.

Comment: @Fred esubmit is in another page sir

Comment: @Simba i will do it later sir haha sorry.

Comment: Try `!empty($_FILES['image'])` instead of `isset($_FILES['image'])`

Comment: @apokryfos tried that sir. still not working same error.

Comment: The if statement there is working when im uploading new image. But when i didn't change the image and update it, the error is showing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you adding slahes to your (temporary) filename?

your line 30:

> ```
> $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
> ```

So to remove the error warning:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) 
     && file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
}
```

- There is a LOT of other things you can / should do with this code but I can't go over it in too much detail with you, but basically you should check that `$_FILES['image']['error'] == 0` to ensure that code only runs if the file has been successfully uploaded.
- Replace

  > ```
  >   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  > ```

With an error check:

```
   if($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0){
```

Which will mean that only an OK uploaded file will then run the `IF` statement contents

- Stop adding slashes, it's not needed.
- Use prepared statements for your SQL queries.
- `Move_uploaded_file` should in a perfect world be given an absolute path rather than a relative path.
- Do you realise that you're `file_get_contents` is getting the ***data*** in a file, not a referece but the actual binary file data. This looks like it's not what you need to be doing at this stage. Your `$image` value isn't clearly used in the code you provide and as rightly pointed out by **apokryfos**, you're actually adding slashes to the retrieved filedata of the image. This is going to simply make your `$image` a garbled mess.

Comment: He's not adding slashes to the temporary filename he's adding slashes to the contents of the temporary file. Why is still a mystery, since it will break the image probably.

Comment: That behaviour by the OP's actually *more* confusing! haha

Comment: It worked already sir no errors. But where do i put the if($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0)?

Comment: @nethken you replace the quoted if statement with the one using the error array feedback

Comment: @nethken it will be a good learning exercise to go through each line of code in your page (as displayed here) and for each function ask *what does this do?* and then *what do I do with the result of this code line?* and ask *What result do I need*? There is a lot of code in your question that is unneeded or doesn't seem to have a clear purpose.

Comment: I just watched a tutorial about that code :( Just a hobby

Comment: @nethken the thing with code is that you improve by reassessing your own work, as much as by watching tutorials, always make time to go back to work you've already done (such as above) and going over it again and asking the sort of questions I ask in the comment above, it can help you establish a clear logic process in your head, which makes writing the code a clearer, smarter and less frustrating experience `:-)`

Comment: Yes sir i'll do it. If u look at my queries you can actually see im a newbie haha. I'll just transfer from c# to php. Im just a student tho. Thanks for ur tips sir. Cheers :D

Comment: @nethken no worries, everyone was a newbie once! Have a good one :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116200/discussion-between-nethken-and-martin).

Comment: @Martin I had tried this logic in my form only attachment is coming other fields are not coming in the mail. Can you please view my question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58129139/9004424

Answer (score 6):

If others still have this issue. That fixed it for me.
Change your php.ini file to

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Explanation: The default setting for the php.ini file is

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

That's why you can't upload images larger than 2 MB.
For Windows you can just search for php.ini in the search bar in the menu bar at the bottom. Then edit the properties with an editor.

Answer (score 0):

For the **file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])** to give you an error of **cannot be empty** it means that it has has no file or nothing has been attached to it in the html part of the code. So check if first of all you have attached anything to it by echoing the value  **file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']).**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain what that code does? How does it solve the given error message?